# multiply variables in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to multiply variables. I need it's value for a keyword to use.
Anyone know how to do it? I only found how to add two variable.

That's what I tried:

```
${Number}=  Run Keyword Evaluate    $First * $Second + $Third
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `Evaluate`, just like you would for any math operator. The problem is that you're using the wrong syntax for variables. Also, you don't need to use `run keyword`

Here is a working example:

```
*** Variables ***
${First}    10
${Second}   20
${Third}    30

*** Test cases ***
Example
    ${result}=    Evaluate    ${First} * ${Second} * ${Third}
    Should be equal as numbers    ${result}    6000
```

Comment: The syntax @Kaamos used is not necessarily incorrect - one could also state that the problem is the variable types are incorrect. If the variables are numeric types like int or float, then the original code would work. Using the syntax $first will inject the value of ${First} directly into the interpreter, whereas ${First} will by converted to text before evaluation (where it will become a number if it "looks" like one). Read the section titled Evaluating expressions in the introduction to the library BuiltIn for information. This is still a good answer.

Comment: @ombre42: you are right, I completely forgot about the special case for `Evaluate`'s handling of the dollar sign. That's a feature I very rarely use.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I used:

```
: FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    10+1
\    ${Result}=    ${no} * ${i}
\    Log    ${no} * ${i} = ${Result}
```

It did not work and gives the error like "*" is not a keyword

Then I used the following and it worked!

```
: FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    10+1
\    ${Result}=    Evaluate    ${no}*${i}
\    Log    ${no} * ${i} = ${Result}
```